# PayPal Website Payment Pro / Payflow Pro Difficulties

Tags: paypal, website-payment-pro

Okey, I'm using PHP/SQL for my built web-cart. I also have the required paypal account (business) so I have an API authentication. I also made a sandbox account and got an API authentication there too.

I've read through alot of the online documentation but it's all a complete mess. Nowhere it says how to use the API codes, but most important which ones to use...

I'll be using Website Payment Pro / Payflow Pro to charge customers using their credit card. They will not be leaving our website, or have to register a PayPal account (what Website Payment Pro offers). All I need now is to know the correct files to download from their SDK, and what should be configured?

Answer (score 1):

The developer guides at the [Paypal Integration Center](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowpro) describe the Payflow Pro API fairly well, and include examples in PHP. If you read through the Payflow Pro Developer's Guide, you will see many examples of using the API.

If you are expecting to cut some code from the Developer's Guide and paste it into your PHP app, you are going to be disappointed. Online payment processing is a huge industry; there are dozens of merchant banks, payment processors, specifications, workflows, card suppliers, versions, fraud and security services, human and programming languages, and best practices available. It is not possible to have a table of every permutation implemented for every business. Even if such a thing existed, no human would live long enough to read it.

You have to determine your workflow ahead of time, read through the Developer Guide, pick out the APIs for the features you need, and implement them. Work through Paypal's [Integration Overview](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview) step by step. This is not a simple process, you are probably looking at weeks of work.

I suggest reconsidering the "they will not be leaving our website" requirement. The Payment Card Industry guidelines for handling credit card and personally-identifying information is very hard to implement. You will also have to leave the origin site to support 3D-Secure.

If this is your first project using online payments and is time-critical, I really suggest using a hosted payment service, like the Paypal shopping cart, and not trying to implement it yourself. Online payment processing is a complex problem, and the results of mistakes can be catastrophic. If you absolutely must implement it yourself, consider hiring a consultant with previous experience.

Comment: Plus, if you are going to accept and transmit CC#'s on your servers you need to be PCI compliant: https://www.paypal.com/pcicompliance which is also going to take time.

Comment: OK that's a bit of crap. Of course PayPal can (and should) provide a standard, cookie-cutter php solution, like, for example, every credit card processor does. Saying "because there's lots of programming languages, that means nobody can ever ever have any code solution ever" is ridiculous.